# How to plot my differential equation with quiver?

Tags: matlab, plot, differential-equations

I want to solve my differential equation and plot velocity vectors but I am having some trouble with that. I tried this:

```
syms y(x);
ode = (1+exp(x))*y*diff(y,x)-2*exp(x) == 0;
ySol = dsolve(ode)

[X,Y] = meshgrid(-2:.2:2);
Z = 2*exp(X)/((1+exp(X)).*Y);
[DX,DY] = gradient(Z,.2,.2);

figure
contour(X,Y,Z)
hold on
quiver(X,Y,DX,DY)
hold off
```

and I get this error:

```
Warning: Matrix is singular to working precision. 
Warning: Contour not rendered for non-finite ZData
```

It is probably something simple that I do not see but I am just starting using Matlab and I cold not find a right way to do my task. Please help me...

EDIT

As bconrad suggested, I changed my Z function like this:

```
Z = 2*exp(X)/((1+exp(X)).*Y);
```

and the previous errors are fixed. However, my prime goal, to plot velocity vectors is not accomplished yet because I get a graph like this:
[image]

Comment: the error is not in the quiver line, is it? It tells you which line it is.

Comment: Yes, it seems that it is in Z = 2*exp(X)/((1+exp(X)).*Y) line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don’t have the ability to check at the moment, but I reckon you want an element by element division in that line. You’re missing a dot on the division, try

```
Z = 2*exp(X)./((1+exp(X)).*Y);
```

I took a closer look once at my station.  The zero-division mentioned by Pablo forces `inf`'s in `Z`, so quiver get's confused when scaling the vectors (understandably) and just doesn't show them.  Try this (with the ode part removed):

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-2 : .2 : 2);
Z = 2 * exp(X) ./ ((1 + exp(X)) .* Y);
Z(isinf(Z)) = nan; % To avoid 0-division problems
[DX, DY] = gradient(Z, .2, .2);

figure
contour(X, Y, Z, 30, 'k')
hold on
quiver(X, Y, DX, DY, 6)
hold off
```

I've done 3 things here:

1. Added the line `Z(isinf(Z)) = nan;` forcing infinite values to be essentially ignored by `quiver`
2. Added the arguments `30, 'k'` to the contour function to show 30 lines, and make them black (a bit more visible)
3. Added the argument `6` to the quiver function.  This overrides the automatic length-scaling of the vectors.

You'll want to play with the arguments in the `contour` and `quiver` functions to make your figure appear as you'd like.

PS: There is a handy `arrow` function on the file exchange that I find gives better control when creating vector field plots. See https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/278-arrow - the ratings do it justice.

Comment: You are right, that fixes the error. However, the plot I get is still not what I want :/

Comment: Take into account, that you also have a 0-division in your calculus. This does not block the plot, but it probably cast some warning...